# How do I find out which is the non serializable object present in spring session

Tags: java, spring, session

I am getting an error
[AsyncSessionPersisterRunnable] Async session persister encountered an exception while trying to persist sessions asynchronously!
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 | org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:140) ~[commons-lang3-3.9.jar:3.9]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:154) ~[commons-lang3-3.9.jar:3.9]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.session.persister.AbstractSessionPersister.updateModelIfNecessary(AbstractSessionPersister.java:31) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.session.persister.AsyncSessionPersisterRunnable.persistSessions(AsyncSessionPersisterRunnable.java:213) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.session.persister.AsyncSessionPersisterRunnable.persistsSessionsFromQueue(AsyncSessionPersisterRunnable.java:130) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.session.persister.AsyncSessionPersisterRunnable.run(AsyncSessionPersisterRunnable.java:80) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant$5.run(AbstractTenant.java:2549) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at de.hybris.platform.core.TenantAwareThreadFactory$1.internalRun(TenantAwareThreadFactory.java:163) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at de.hybris.platform.core.threadregistry.RegistrableThread.run(RegistrableThread.java:124) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 | Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1187) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1572) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1529) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1438) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1181) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:350) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1424) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1034.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1070) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1516) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1438) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.571 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1181) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.572 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1572) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.572 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1529) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.572 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1438) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.572 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1181) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.572 |     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:350) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2022/11/02 03:53:56.572 |     at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:138) ~[commons-lang3-3.9.jar:3.9]